# How to show image from server to my ImageView in Android

Tags: android, url, imageview

I have an image link from server, I want to show it in my android app, I tried this code but not worked for

```
imageview.setImageURI(Uri.parse("pathofimage"));
```

Image link is like [http:/54.70.37.32/uploads/Provider_profile_pic.jpg](http://http:/54.70.37.32/uploads/Provider__profile_pic.jpg)

Comment: First of all where is your code ? I can't see

Comment: What did your internet search turn up?

Comment: update your image link

Comment: Try using glide. Faster than Picasso, picture quality better than picasso

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Picasso API which has many builtin functions for example:

- Cache Images
- Fast loading
- Masking images

  **Now How to use Picasso Library for loading the ImageViews, here it is step by step.**

  1. Add Picasso API in your app.gradle file

     compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
  2. Then Sync your gradle
  3. Now you can load image with following simple line

     Picasso.with(context).load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEIKP.jpg").into(imageView);

for further Info go to : [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: your "step by step" should start at step 1 

Comment: Yeah thanks, I am updating it.

Answer (score 2):

Use Picasso Library like this.
Gradle dependency:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

then in your code use this to set image

```
Picasso.with(YOUR_ACTIVITY_INSTANCE).
load(IMAGE_URL).into(IMAGE_VIEW);
```

you can also use Glide.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

```
   ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleton instance
// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and display Bitmap in ImageView (or any other view 
//  which implements ImageAware interface)
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and return Bitmap to callback
imageLoader.loadImage(imageUri, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
@Override
public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
    // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
}
});
```